# Finding Orthonormal Basis and minimum distance

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $M$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ spanned by the vectors $$v_1=(1,0,0,0)$$

$$v_2 = (1,0,1,0)$$

$$v_3=(0,1,0,1)$$

A) Find a basis $M$ which is orthnormal with respect to the usual inner product on $\mathbb{R}^4$

I'm very rusty on functional analysis right now but am I suppose to use Gram Schmidt? If so, then I get $$e_1=(1,0,0,0)$$

$$e_2=(0,0,1,0)$$

$$e_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(0,1,0,1)$$

Am I on the right track?

B) Find the vector $w$ in $M$ at minimum distance from $w_0=(1,1,0,0)$.

My conjecture here is to use the previous orthonormal basis and then use a special proposition that says the solution will be the projection of $w_0$ onto $M$. Then $$(Pf)(w_0)=\langle w_0,e_1 \rangle e_1+\langle w_0,e_2 \rangle e_2 + \langle w_0,e_3 \rangle e_3$$.

Comment: I think you mean the projection of $w_0$ into M?

Comment: Everything you wrote here seems great. ($Pf$ is the name of your projection function, right?)

Comment: Yes sorry editing now @DBF

Comment: @Tunococ yes I should define that as well

Comment: "basis $M$" should be replaced with "basis of $M$" or "basis for $M$". $\;$

Answer (score 1):

If you add $e_4=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(0,1,0,-1)$ to your set of $e_1,e_2,e_3$, you get an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^4$. Then you can easily express $w_0=(1,1,0,0)$ in terms of $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ like this

$w_0=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3+x_4e_4$,

where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are some numbers in $\mathbb R$.

Then $x_4$ gives the distance from the end point of $w_0$ to $M$ and $w=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3$.

Comment: Do I need 4? Or is this just another way of doing it with respect to the method specified above?

Comment: You don't. Your way of doing it is fine. I just wanted to give you a broader perspective. Note that you can get your projection formula by taking the relevant dot products. For instance, $x_1=w_0\cdot e_1=\langle w_0,e_1\rangle$.